# How to create an adjacency matrix from an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: matlab, graph

I have an Excel spreadsheet which depicts a binary adjacency matrix in the form shown below (with about a 1000 nodes):-

[image]

I wish to create the same adjacency matrix in MATLAB out of this Excel file. However, I'm a beginner in MATLAB. Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to read a matrix from an Excel file into Matlab.  If it's something you only need to do once, the best way is probably just the copy-and-paste method.  If you need to do things programmatically, you probably want to use `xlsread`.  Here's some documentation of both methods (and a couple of others) from the company's website:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/ways-to-import-spreadsheets.html

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot! :)

Comment: To elaborate on copy and paste, you would create some variable in Matlab via something like `x = 0;` then double click `x` in your workspace iwndow, then copy and paste.